# Remove vertical space after new chapters in listofalgorithms

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, algorithm2e

When generating list of algorithms, the command `\listofalgorithms` automatically inserts a 10pt `vspace` after the last algorithm caption in a chapter. I need to remove this vertical space in such a way that all algorithms in all chapters align vertically similar.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

This stems from a redefinition of `\@chapter` by [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e):

```
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup 
\expandafter\ifx\csname @chapter\endcsname\relax\else 
  \let\algocf@original@chapter=\@chapter% 
  \def\@chapter[#1]#2{\algocf@original@chapter[#1]{#2}\addtocontents{loa}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}% 
\fi
```

It stores `\@chapter` and then redefines it to `\addvspace{10\p@}` similar to the traditional way chapters inserts spaces between figures/tables in the LoF/LoT.

To avoid this, load `algorithm2e` in the following way:

```
\makeatletter
\let\old@chapter\@chapter% Store \@chapter
\usepackage[<opts>]{algorithm2e}
\let\@chapter\old@chapter% Restore \@chapter
\makeatother
```

---

Here's a minimal example *without* the above code:

[image]

...and *with*:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\makeatletter
\let\old@chapter\@chapter% Store \@chapter
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\let\@chapter\old@chapter% Restore \@chapter
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\listofalgorithms
\chapter{First chapter}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{An algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{An algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{An algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{An algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\chapter{Last chapter}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{An algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{An algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment out the additions and recompile twice to switch between the two.

Comment: @SoheilShafiee: If this answered your question, see [How do you accept an answer?](http://goo.gl/hzFkJ)

Comment: Works like charm